# Aborting a Read() call from another goroutine

Tags: io, go

I'm working on an IMAP server, and one of the operations is to upgrade the connection to use TLS (via the `STARTTLS` command).  Our current architecture has one goroutine reading data from the socket, parsing the commands, and then sending logical commands over a channel.  Another goroutine reads from that channel and executes the commands.  This works great in general.

When executing `STARTTLS`, though, we need to stop the current in-progress `Read()` call, otherwise that `Read()` will consume bytes from the TLS handshake.  We can insert another class in between, but then that class will be blocked on the `Read()` call and we have the same problem.  If the network connection were a channel, we could add another signal channel and use a `select{}` block to stop reading, but network connections aren't channels (and simply wrapping it in a goroutine and channel just moves the problem to that goroutine).

Is there any way to stop a `Read()` call once it's begun, without waiting for a timeout to expire or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

`Read()` call relies on your operating system behaviour under the hood. And its behaviour relies on socket behaviour.

If you're familiar with socket interface (which is almost a standard between operating systems with some small differences), you'll see that using synchronous communication mode for socket, `read` system call always blocks thread's execution until time out value expires, and you can't change this behaviour.

Go uses synchronous I/O under the hood for all its needs because goroutines make asynchronous communication unneeded by design.

There's also a way to break `read`: by shutting down the socket manually, which is not the best design decision for ones code, and in your specific case. So you should better play with smaller timeouts I think, or redesign your code to work in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

There's really not much you can do to *stop* a `Read` call, unless you `SetReadDeadline`, or `Close` the connection.

One thing you could do is buffer it with the `bufio` package. This will allow you to [Peek](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Peek) without actually reading something off the buffer. `Peek` will block just like `Read` does, but will allow you to decide what to do when something is available to read.